# Java Spring: no take the variable into file-properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my repository there are file-properties with this var:

```
wizard.start.scriptNameAndroid=install-android.bat
```

This is a part of my file **spring-businss.xml**:

```
<bean id="wizardService" class="business.services.WizardServiceImpl">
    <property name="nameFileAndroid" value="${wizard.start.scriptNameAndroid}"/>        
</bean>
```

This is my class Java

```
public class WizardServiceImpl implements WizardService {
    private static String nameFileAndroid="";  

[...]

    public String getNameFileAndroid() {
        return nameFileAndroid;
    }
    public void setNameFileAndroid(String nameFileAndroid) {
        this.nameFileAndroid = nameFileAndroid;
    } 
}
```

When i use the variable *nameFileAndroid* the program take always the value that i set into the class.
How can i do priority of file file-properties?

Comment: Do you have a `context:property-placeholder` definition in your context?

Comment: Is this variable placed inside .properties fie?

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalHyder yes!

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't Inject it using:

```
@Value("${wizard.start.scriptNameAndroid}")
private static String nameFileAndroid;
```

it will take value from your properties file.

Answer (score 0):

If that variable is in .properties file you can refer to its value like this:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "business.services.*" })  
@PropertySource("classpath:file.properties")
public class WizardServiceImpl implements WizardService {

    @Autowired
    private Environment enviro;

    private static String nameFileAndroid = enviro.getProperty("wizard.start.scriptNameAndroid");
}
```

**`Another way`**

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "business.services.*" })  
@PropertySource("classpath:file.properties")
public class WizardServiceImpl implements WizardService {

    @Value("${wizard.start.scriptNameAndroid}")
    private static String nameFileAndroid;

    //Register bean to enable ${} value wiring
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
   }
}
```

Or if you still prefer XML way:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="resources/file.properties" />
```

Hope i helped. :)